# How can I line up my CSS DIVs

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS and HTML:

```
div#actionList { float: left; height: 25px; margin: 10px; padding: 0px; }
div#actionList div { float: left; }

<div id="bdy">  
   <div id="actionList" class="btn1" >
      <div>xx</div>
      <div style="margin: 0 0 0 20px;">AAA</div>
      <div style="margin: 0 0 0 5px; ">BBB</div>
   </div>
   <div id="detailData">
      CCC
   </div>    
</div>
```

This displays as:

```
   AAA BBB CCC
```

What I would like to do is to have this display as:

```
   AAA BBB

   CCC
```

Can someone tell me how I can do this. How I can make the detailData DIV data 
start below the "actionList" information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div#detailData { clear : both; }​
```

This will put the `#detailData` div on it's own line:

> The clear CSS property specifies whether an element can be next to
>   floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared)
>   below them.

*Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/clear*

And a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KBges/

Answer (score 0):

try adding clear: both; to the css for id detailData